# boostrap 4 Equal heights not working

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

What is the way of making div's have equal heights within the row?

it says everywhere that bootstrap4 is flex by default, but it doesn't work for some unknown reason

```
        <div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <div class="content" >
            <div class="sub_title"> HISTORY </div>
            <div class="desc"> Sometext </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="sub_title">
              <div class="number"> 2012 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="desc"> some other text </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg ">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="sub_title">
              <div class="number"> 2014 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="desc"> More text </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg ">
          <div class="content">
            <div class="sub_title">
              <div class="number"> 2017 </div>
            </div>
            <div class="desc"> Text here too </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
```

the scss

```
.content {
        @extend .effect8;
        background: white;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px 30px 20px;
        span {
          display: block;
          p {
            font-weight: bold;
          }
        }
      }

.sub_title {
  font-size: 1.5em;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  display: block;
  color: $blue;
  margin: 10px auto;
}
```

this is the scss for the content and the sub_title class

Comment: Can't say without seeing your code

Comment: Here take a [look at this google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=bootstrap+4+equal+height&oq=bootstrap+4+equal+height&aqs=chrome..69i57.8046j0j7&client=ms-android-samsung&sourceid=chrome-mobile&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: use only col. It will work

Comment: @ZimSystem here's the code

Comment: This should work fine for equal heights. Is there CSS for the content, sub_title, etc?

Comment: @ZimSystem updated again

Answer (score 0):

If you want `.content` to be full height on each `.col`, the content should have `height:100%;`. I don't know the CSS def of `.effect8`.

```
.content {
        background: white;
        margin: 10px;
        padding: 10px 30px 20px;
        height: 100%;
        span {
          display: block;
          p {
            font-weight: bold;
          }
        }
 }
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/B4g6TlSDkA

Comment: this makes every content fill the height of the screen and not the col, 
I removed the effect8, it's just a dropshadow effect.
as I can see, the col's are equal height, the content is the one that doesn't fill it's parent div's height

Comment: `height:100%` does *not* make `.content` fill the screen... It makes it fill the height of the parent. The only way `.content` would fill screen height would be `position: fixed`.

Comment: it's not supposed to fill the screen, but that is what is happening.

Comment: It's not happening for me. The content fills the height of the tallest col.

Comment: I will try to figure out what is causing this issue, there must be something in my code somewhere that is messing it all up for me. thanks for the help though

Answer (score -1):

Actually it depend of browser, e.g In **Safari** it may not work, and also in **Internet Explorer** may have unwanted behaviors.

If you're really want equal and avoid cross browser issue try JS solution e.g http://brm.io/jquery-match-height/

Comment: this works, but not on all of the divs, maybe I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: Actually that is what I write up here.

Comment: let me rephrase that: I tried your JS solution, it doesn't work on all div's